# Android call onactivityresult from onitemclick

Tags: android

I need to pass the value using intent from onItemClick method from 1.java to onActivityResult in 2.Java

1.java

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
{     

    int songindex=position; 
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Play.class);
    intent2.putExtra("songindex",songindex);
    setResult(100, intent2);
    startActivity(intent2);


}
```

2.java

```
public class Play extends Activity {
MediaPlayer mp;
int currentsong=0;  
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play);
    currentsong=getIntent().getIntExtra("songindex",-1);

}



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==100)
        {
            //Intent intent1=getIntent();
            //currentsong=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("songindex");
            pl(currentsong);
        }
    }
```

my problem is intent value not passed from 1.java to 2.java and when onItemClick is clicked i need to pass the value using intent and call the method pl(songindex)

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand how `onActivityResult()` works. If you want to get the value from the extra in `2.java`, use `getIntent().getIntExtra("songindex", -1)` in `onCreate()` (as you actually do). More information about Activities and how to pass values between them can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
```

Is only called after activities started by startActivityForResult() finish.  aka if 2.java called 1.java then 1.java triggers onActivityResult when it finishes.

```
currentsong=getIntent().getIntExtra("songindex",-1);
```

should contain the value of songindex from 1.java

```
intent2.putExtra("songindex",songindex);
```

Look at this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#overview_accessdata

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that onActivityResult method is executed in the activity that starts a new one, not in the launched activity (Play class in your example).

So you can get the extra data inside the intent that launched the Player activity inside the onCreate method of the launched activity (Player) and set the attribute value in that way.

In addition you can use setResult method in the launched activity (Play) and the onActivityResult method of the caller activity (1) will be executed, if you started the Player activity for result.